# Tikz: How to shade a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I have made a graph with TikZ and now I would like to apply a shading to some of the nodes but I can't seem to find out how to do that.

This doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every node/.append style={minimum size=.7cm, draw,circle,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries,inner sep=0.05cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sh/.style={shade,shading=axis,shading angle=45,left color=red,right color=green}]
  \node                                 (x1) {$x_1$};
  \node[node distance=3cm,right of=x1]  (x2) {$x_2$};
  \node[node distance=3cm,right of=x2]  (x3) {$x_3$};

  \node[node distance=1cm,below of=x1]  (1) [sh] {};
  \node[node distance=1cm,below of=x2]  (2) [sh] {};
  \node[node distance=1cm,below of=x3]  (3) [sh] {};
  \node[node distance=1.5cm,below of=1] (4) {};
  \node[node distance=1.5cm,below of=2] (5) {};
  \node[node distance=1.5cm,below of=3] (6) {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {x1/1,x2/2,x3/3,1/4,2/5,3/6,4/5,5/6} \draw (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume by "this doesn't work", you mean that your nodes get shaded, but the parameter `shading angle=45` is ignored? To get a rotated linear shading, you'll have to use `top color` and `bottom color` instead of `left color` and `right` color, and the `shading angle` parameter needs to be provided last.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: @Jake: I assume this is an answer ;-)

Comment: @Jake why change to `top` and `bottom`? `left` and `right` will also work, provided `shading angle` is used last.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You're right! (Makes sense, too)

Comment: You do not have to use `shading=axis` option, it is the default one. The application of either `left color` or `right color` changes that angle automatically to 90 degrees.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the `shading angle` needs to be the last definition.

In the example I've used a `matrix of math nodes` just to show a different way to achieve the same goal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
  mymx/.style={ matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    row sep=3mm, column sep=2cm,
    nodes={ minimum size=.7cm, draw, circle,
      font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries, inner sep=0.05cm } },
  sh/.style={ shade, shading=axis, left color=red, right color=green,
    shading angle=45 } }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[mymx,row 2/.style={every node/.append style=sh}] (mx) {
    x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
    &&\\[5mm]
    &&\\
  };
  \draw (mx-1-1) -- (mx-2-1) -- (mx-3-1) -- (mx-3-2) -- (mx-3-3) -- (mx-2-3) -- (mx-1-3)
    (mx-3-2) -- (mx-2-2) -- (mx-1-2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]